# Remove transparency/alpha from any image using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alphablending

How do I replace the alpha channel of any image (png, jpg, rgb, rbga) with specified background color?  It must also work with images that do not have an alpha channel.

Answer (score 41):

This can be done by checking if the image is transparent

```
def remove_transparency(im, bg_colour=(255, 255, 255)):

    # Only process if image has transparency (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
    if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (im.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in im.info):

        # Need to convert to RGBA if LA format due to a bug in PIL (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
        alpha = im.convert('RGBA').split()[-1]

        # Create a new background image of our matt color.
        # Must be RGBA because paste requires both images have the same format
        # (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8720632  and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9459208)
        bg = Image.new("RGBA", im.size, bg_colour + (255,))
        bg.paste(im, mask=alpha)
        return bg

    else:
        return im
```

Comment: In modern versions of Pillow you can probably use `.getchannel('A')` instead of `.split()[-1]`.

Comment: After pasting the image onto the background, I had to also convert to RGB using `bg.convert('RGB')`

Answer (score 22):

I'd suggest using [`Image.alpha_composite`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite).
This code can avoid a `tuple index out of range` error if png has no alpha channel.

```
from PIL import Image

png = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGBA')
background = Image.new('RGBA', png.size, (255,255,255))

alpha_composite = Image.alpha_composite(background, png)
alpha_composite.save('foo.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=80)
```

I also recommend you inspect both results with a `image.show()`.

Credits for this answer goes to [shuuji3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204782/shuuji3) and others who helped build a vast answers repertoire in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507138/2628864).

Comment: If the source image is always a PNG, this should be fine, but if it may encounter an image type that doesn't have transparency, e.g. a .jpg, this produces an `OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`. I added a check when opening the image to resolve this.

Answer (score 4):

I updated [Vincius M's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62414364/5595995) with the user, tutuDajuju, suggestion to make [height, width, 3] matrix (not [height, width, 4]):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

png = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGBA')
background = Image.new('RGBA', png.size, (255,255,255))

alpha_composite = Image.alpha_composite(background, png)
# if you check the matrix dimension, channel, it would be still 4.  
h, w, channel = np.asarray(alpha_composite).shape

alpha_composite_3 = alpha_composite.convert('RGB')
# if you check the matrix dimension, channel, it would be 3.  
h, w, channel = np.asarray(alpha_composite_3).shape
```

Comment: You need to add the `.shape` to the numpy array to accessthe `h, w, channel` variables.

Comment: @jegertor Thanks for correction. Next time, please go head to edit.