# ImageOps.autocontrast turns white background black even when ignore=255 is set

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Applying

```
img = Image.open("original.png").convert("L") 
edited = ImageOps.autocontrast(img, cutoff=1, ignore=255, preserve_tone=True)
edited.save("autocontrast.png")
```

original.png

[image]

autocontrast.png

[image]

Expected result: White space above right stays white and is not black after applying ImageOps.autocontrast

-> any ideas what I do wrong?

Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Pillow 8.4.0

Comment: Have you printed those values to make sure they are actually 255?  Depending on the source, then might have a different value.  You might consider using `img.getpixel` to fetch a value from that region.

Comment: When opening the image in an editor e.g. photopea , the area is transparent and values are 0, even if I set ignore=0 it does not keep the white border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cute one!  In your original image, those pixels actually ARE black (RGB = (0,0,0)), but they have an alpha value of 0, so the white you are seeing in the background window showing through.  The alpha gets dropped when you convert to 'L'.

If you do `ignore=0`, it should do what you expect.

Comment: When opening the image in an editor e.g. photopea , the area is transparent and values are 0, even if I set ignore=0 it does not keep the white border.

Comment: It's NOT a white border.  It never was.  It is a TRANSPARENT border.  You see it as white here because the StackOverflow window background color is white.  If StackOverflow used a pink background, you would see a pink region.  The white (or pink) pixels are not part of your image.  If you REALLY want to, you can use `alpha_composite` to force those pixels to white before converting to `L`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859140/remove-transparency-alpha-from-any-image-using-pil

Comment: Thanks , alpha_composite did the trick