# How to Remove Residuals in Images using Python

Tags: python, image-processing

Image1 contains rectangles with residuals
[image: Image1]

and Image2 represents the desired result.
[image: Image2]

I want to achieve the same result as Image2 using Image1 in Python, but I'm unsure if it's possible and have no idea about the necessary methods.

I tried to use the transparency of the image to remove it, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: Regardless of what you use to implement it, what *logic* are you using to identify the "residuals"?

Comment: It may be difficult to give you specific direction without more information, but if you have a 4 channel `png` image, you could likely get away with the methods suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859140/remove-transparency-alpha-from-any-image-using-pil

Comment: You can use thresholding and contour detection to identify and remove unwanted artifacts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you get on with my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *"residual"* images are less saturated than the *"core"* images, so you can separate the *"resiiduals"* from the *"cores"* in HSV colourspace, see [Wikipedia HSV article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Using **ImageMagick**, I can convert your image to HSV colourspace, discard the `H` and `V` channels and then threshold the Saturation channel to find the most saturated areas like this:

```
magick INPUT.PNG -colorspace HSV -separate -delete 0,2 -threshold 75% rssult.png
```

[image]

---

Using Python and OpenCV, that looks roughly like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv.imread(YOURIMAGE)

# Convert to HSV colourspace and split channels
hsv = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
H, S, V = cv.split(hsv)

# Make mask of areas of high saturation 
coreMask = S > 200

# Scale up from range 0..1 to range 0..255 and save as PNG
cv.imwrite('result.png', coreMask * 255)
```

---

If I split the image into its H, S and V components and plot H (Hue) on the left, S (Saturation) in the centre and V (Value, i.e. brightness) on the right, you can see in the central S (Saturation) image that the pixel values are higher for your *"core"* shapes and lower for your *"residuals"*:

[image]