# Trouble creating PIL Image object from canvas tag with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a PIL Image object based on a `canvas` tag extracted with Selenium from [this](http://www.trt22.jus.br/portal/home.jsp) website. The goal is to use `pytesseract` and get the captcha content. My code doesn't raise any errors, but the image created is all black.

My code so far:

```
# Run JS code to get data URI
png_url = driver.execute_script(
        'return document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png");')
# Parse the URI to get only the base64 part
str_base64 = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', png_url).group(1)
# Convert it to binary
str_decoded = str_base64.decode('base64')
# Create and show Image object
image = Image.open(StringIO(str_decoded))
image.show()    
# Read image with pytesseract
recaptcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

I don't know why the image is all black. My code is based on [this](https://qxf2.com/blog/selenium-html5-canvas-verify-what-was-drawn/) tutorial, which saves the image. I dont want to save the image, I want it to be in memory only.

Edit:

I have saved the image in filesystem and the image is saving ok, but with transparent background, thus appearing black when showed. How can I make the background white?

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do is extract the background following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859140/remove-transparency-alpha-from-any-image-using-pil) answer:

```
def remove_transparency(im, bg_colour=(255, 255, 255)):

    # Only process if image has transparency (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
    if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (im.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in im.info):

        # Need to convert to RGBA if LA format due to a bug in PIL (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
        alpha = im.convert('RGBA').split()[-1]

        # Create a new background image of our matt color.
        # Must be RGBA because paste requires both images have the same format
        # (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720632  and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459208)
        bg = Image.new("RGBA", im.size, bg_colour + (255,))
        bg.paste(im, mask=alpha)
        return bg

    else:
        return im
```

The complete code then:

```
png_url = driver.execute_script(
            'return document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png");')
str_base64 = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', png_url).group(1)
# Convert it to binary
str_decoded = str_base64.decode('base64')
image = Image.open(StringIO(str_decoded))
image = remove_transparency(image)
recaptcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(image).replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a RGB white image and paste your RGBA image into it. Solution may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil/9459208#9459208), but there are other ways too. I suggest numpy and opencv.