# convert pillow Image object to JpegImageFile object

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, crop

I cropped an jpeg image, but the cropped image type is

```
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

how can i convert it to

```
<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
```

?

thank you!

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get("https://mamahelpers.co/assets/images/faq/32B.JPG").content))
img2 = img.crop((1,20,50,80))

print(type(img)) # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
print(type(img2)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert to jpeg using Pillow in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258461/convert-png-to-jpeg-using-pillow-in-python)

Comment: @PatrickArtner already seen this question, solution didn't worked in my case

Comment: Its good to cite questions you researched in your post - how should we know what you already tried and what did not work? Why did it not work in your case? Convert your PIL.Image.Image to RGB, save it as JPG, Reopen it using `myfile = PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile('filename.jpg')` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner writing to disk is too expensive operation, that's why i'm asking from a community for another solution.

UPD: included code to question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not want a pyhsical file, do use a memory file:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO    

img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get("https://mamahelpers.co/assets/images/faq/32B.JPG").content))
img2 = img.crop((1,20,50,80))

b = BytesIO()
img2.save(b,format="jpeg")
img3 = Image.open(b)

print(type(img))  # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
print(type(img2)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'> 
print(type(img3)) # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
```

ByteIO is a stream-obj, it is probably wise to `close()` it at some point when no longer needed.