# Error when coverting TIF images into jpg with Python

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I have a folder that contains 2000 TIF images and I want to convert them to jpg images. 
I wrote two codes and both work well until they convert 370 images and then they raise an error

Here is my first code :

```
DestPath='/media/jack/Elements/ToJPG95/'
from PIL import Image
import os
def change(path, row):
  filename1=path+row
  filename=row.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
  im = Image.open(filename1)
  img= im.convert('RGB')
  Dest=os.path.join(DestPath,filename)
  img.save(Dest, format='JPEG',quality=95)


import csv
sourcePath='/media/jack/Elements/TifImages/'
with open("TIFFnames.csv") as f:
    filtered = (line.replace('\n', '') for line in f)
    reader = csv.reader(filtered)
    for row in filtered:
       change(sourcePath , row)
```

and here is my second code which I ran in inside the folder that has the images :

```
from PIL import Image  # Python Image Library - Image Processing
import glob
DestPath='/media/jack/Elements/ToJPG95/'
print(glob.glob("*.TIF"))
for file in glob.glob("*.TIF"):
    im = Image.open(file)
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    rgb_im.save(DestPath+file.replace("TIF", "jpg"), quality=95)
# based on SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258974/5086335
```

they convert up to 370 images and then give an error
Here is the error I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conmg.py", line 7, in <module>
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 873, in convert
    self.load()
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1070, in load
    return self._load_libtiff()
  File "/home/jack/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1182, in _load_libtiff
    raise OSError(err)
OSError: -2
```

I have tried imagemagick mentioned in the solution [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60401/batch-processing-tif-images-converting-tif-to-jpeg)

but this is what I am getting when I click enter to run the command:

```
jack@jack-dell:/media/jack/Elements/TifImages$ for f in *.tif; do  echo "Converting $f"; convert "$f"  "$(basename "$f" .tif).jpg"
> 
> 
> 
>
```

As you can see, it does nothing 
I think the codes work well but for some reason they fail after converting 370 images
I am running on a 6 TB external hard drive.
Can any one tell me please whats wrong ?

Comment: Is there a certain file that it is erroring on?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington No. I copied the whole error message and pasted it here.

Comment: @IainShelvington No. I copied the whole error message and pasted it here.

Comment: Perhaps you have a corrupt file.

Comment: Btw, why not just use mogrify? `magick mogrify -format JPEG -quality 95 *.tif`

Comment: @fmw42 As you said. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarkSetchell I used mogrify and it gave me an error saying that the files do not  exist

Comment: Try running `ls *.tif` to see how many TIFFs you have in that directory.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it says : ls: cannot access '*.tif': No such file or directory

Comment: That means you don't have any files ending in `tif` in that directory. Unix is sensitive to upper/lower case, by the way. Maybe you have `*TIF`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried to capitalize it  so I entered ls *.TIF and it worked it listed the files. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fmw42 says, you likely have a problem with the 370th file (corrupt, or some ill-supported TIFF variant). You bash code will convert all the files that can be read, it doesn't work because you are missing a closing `done`:

```
 for f in *.tif; do  echo "Converting $f"; convert "$f"  "$(basename "$f" .tif).jpg" ; done
```

Your Python would also convert all the readable files if you use try/except to catch errors and continue with the next file:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.TIF"):
    try: 
        im = Image.open(file)
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save(DestPath+file.replace("TIF", "jpg"), quality=95)
    except:
        print('File not converted:',file)
```

Comment: The Python code worked well Thanks a lot. The bash script did not work Here is the error : convert-im6.q16: no images defined `*.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.

Comment: But the Python works. it printed the file that caused the problem and continued working. you and @fmw42 saved my life. Thank you both

Comment: Upvote is fine, but please consider accepting the answer (checkmark below the votes) so that it shows as having a satisfactory answer.