# Saving to EPS not supported in Python Pillow?

Tags: python, image, save, python-imaging-library, file-format

I am trying to convert an image from PNG to EPS using Pillow. The following code gives an error:

```
from PIL import Image

Image.open("Image1.png").save("Image1.eps", fmt='EPS')
```

Which reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pbreach/Dropbox/Personal/FigureConversion/convert.py", line 15, in <module>
    convert_image(in_name, out_name, fmt='EPS')
  File "C:/Users/pbreach/Dropbox/Personal/FigureConversion/convert.py", line 4, in convert_image
    Image.open(in_name).save(out_name, fmt)
  File "C:\Users\pbreach\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1826, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\pbreach\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py", line 362, in _save
    raise ValueError("image mode is not supported")
ValueError: image mode is not supported
```

Is EPS really not supported? In the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#eps) EPS is second on the list of fully supported formats. Is there anything that I need to do if this is not the case?

Weirdly enough, if I do `Image.open("Image1.png").save("Image1.jpg", fmt='EPS')` it works but saves to JPG.

Answer (score 3):

Pillow supports EPS, but cannot write it with alpha channel (`RGBA`, `LA`)
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=eps#eps:

> Pillow identifies EPS files containing image data, and can read files
>   that contain embedded raster images (ImageData descriptors). If
>   Ghostscript is available, other EPS files can be read as well. The EPS
>   driver can also write EPS images. The EPS driver can read EPS images
>   in L, LAB, RGB and CMYK mode, but Ghostscript may convert the images
>   to RGB mode rather than leaving them in the original color space. The
>   EPS driver can write images in L, RGB and CMYK modes.

Helped for me to convert the image to `RGB` mode before saving

```
from PIL import Image

fig = Image.open("Image1.png")

if fig.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
    # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=eps#eps
    print('Current figure mode "{}" cannot be directly saved to .eps and should be converted (e.g. to "RGB")'.format(fig.mode))
    fig = fig.convert('RGB')

out_fig = "Image1.eps"
fig.save(out_fig)
fig.close()
```

But sometimes I had problems: got black background in `.eps` instead of transparent `.png`. For me helped `remove_transparency()` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859141/7444782 to substitute the transparent background to a specified color (white by default)

```
from PIL import Image

def remove_transparency(im, bg_color=(255, 255, 255)):
    """
    Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859141/7444782
    """
    # Only process if image has transparency (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
    if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (im.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in im.info):

        # Need to convert to RGBA if LA format due to a bug in PIL (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
        alpha = im.convert('RGBA').split()[-1]

        # Create a new background image of our matt color.
        # Must be RGBA because paste requires both images have the same format
        # (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8720632  and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9459208)
        bg = Image.new("RGBA", im.size, bg_color + (255,))
        bg.paste(im, mask=alpha)
        return bg
    else:
        return im

fig = Image.open("Image1.png")

if fig.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
    # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=eps#eps
    print('Current figure mode "{}" cannot be directly saved to .eps and should be converted (e.g. to "RGB")'.format(fig.mode))
    fig = remove_transparency(fig)
    fig = fig.convert('RGB')

out_fig = "Image1.eps"
fig.save(out_fig)
fig.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have a png with an alpha channel. EPS in PIL does not support transparency in raster images.

So if you remove the alpha channel by `im[:,:,0:2]` it might just work like a charm.
It will be more than one line, however.