# Load image on python CheckListCtrl with transparency

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm starting to use WX GUI on python, and on my "Hello Word" project I'm trying to create a program with the ability to read any image and show it as icon into a CheckListCtrl column. I've done the first part (read the image and draw it into the CheckListCtrl), but I'm not able to load a PNG image and keep the transparency on that icon.

My code is the following:

```
'''
17 June 2018
@autor: Daniel Carrasco
'''

import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin
import sys
from pathlib import Path

BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (240, 240, 240, 255);

class CheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER,
              size=wx.Size(395, 467), pos=wx.Point(10, 20));
    CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self);
    ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self);

#====================================================================
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.dataFolder = {
      "images": Path("images/")
    }

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs);

    icon = wx.Icon("icons.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
    self.SetIcon(icon);

    self.createWidgets();
    self.createButtons();
    self.Show();


  #----------------------------------------------------------
  def exitGUI(self, event):       # callback
    self.Destroy();

  #----------------------------------------------------------
  def createWidgets(self):
    self.CreateStatusBar();      # wxPython built-in method
    self.createMenu();

    # Creamos el panel
    boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer();

    panel = wx.Panel(self);
    panel.SetBackgroundColour(BACKGROUNDCOLOR);
    panel.SetSizerAndFit(boxSizer);

    staticBox = wx.StaticBox( panel, -1, "Listado de Saves", size=(415, 500),
              pos=wx.Point(5, 0) )   
    self.statBoxSizerV = wx.StaticBoxSizer(staticBox, wx.VERTICAL)

    # Lista de items
    self.itemList = CheckListCtrl(staticBox);
    self.itemList.InsertColumn(0, '', width=32);
    self.itemList.InsertColumn(1, 'Icono', width=52);
    self.itemList.InsertColumn(2, 'Título', width=140);

    self.il_Small = self.itemList.GetImageList(wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL);
    self.il = wx.ImageList(48, 48, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL);
    self.itemList.SetImageList(self.il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL);

    image = wx.Image(str(self.dataFolder["images"] / "tick_1.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY);
    self.il.Add(wx.Bitmap(image));

    image = wx.Image(str(self.dataFolder["images"] / 'tick_2.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY);
    self.il.Add(wx.Bitmap(image));

    image = wx.Image(str(self.dataFolder["images"] / 'exit.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY );
    for x in range(0, 4):
      for y in range(0, 4):
        image.SetAlpha(x, y, 0);
    image = image.Scale(40, 40, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    image = image.Size(wx.Size(48,48), wx.Point(4,4), 255, 255, 255);
#    image.ClearAlpha();
    self.il.Add(wx.Bitmap(image));

    image = wx.Image(str(self.dataFolder["images"] / 'test.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY );
    image = image.Scale(40, 40, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    image = image.Size(wx.Size(48,48), wx.Point(4,4), 255, 255, 255);
    self.il.Add(image.ConvertToBitmap());

    index = self.itemList.InsertItem(sys.maxsize, "test");
    self.itemList.SetItemColumnImage(0, 1, 3)
    #self.itemList.Append("Prueba");

  #----------------------------------------------------------
  def createButtons(self):
    pass

  #----------------------------------------------------------
  def createMenu(self):
    # Menú Archivo
    APP_EXIT = 1;
    mArchivo = wx.Menu();
    qmi = wx.MenuItem(mArchivo, APP_EXIT, '&Salir\tCtrl+Q');
    image = wx.Image(str(self.dataFolder["images"] / 'exit.png'),wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    image = image.Scale(16, 16, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    qmi.SetBitmap(image.ConvertToBitmap());
    mArchivo.Append(qmi);
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.exitGUI, id=APP_EXIT);

    # Barra de menús
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar();

    menuBar.Append(mArchivo, "&Archivo");

    # Seteamos la barra de menús
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar);


#======================
# Start GUI
#======================
app = wx.App()
MainFrame(None, style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX, title="Savegame Linker", size=(485,587))
app.MainLoop()
```

This code just read the image into and Image object, then scale the image and add a border resizing. The problem is that PNG transparency is not kept and only the border is transparent:

[image: Transparency Wrong]

If I remove the image transparency with Photoshop (adding white background), then the image is showed with the transparency I want:

[image: transparency OK]

Is there any way to keep the PNG transparency on CheckListCtrl, or at least add a white background to the image (that looks like an alternative solution). I want to do it if posible using only WX, because I think that use pillow module for example, just for remove transparency, is not an optimal solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the right way is converting the transparency into mask. I've already tested it, but looks like I've used the function after other that made it fail.

```
image = wx.Image(str(self.dataFolder["images"] / 'test.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY );
image = image.Scale(40, 40, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH);
image.ConvertAlphaToMask(threshold=50);
image = image.Size(wx.Size(48,48), wx.Point(4,4), 255, 255, 255);
self.il.Add(image.ConvertToBitmap());
```

The last time I'd tried the function was after the image.Size function, and then it fails (maybe the Size function removes the transparency), but if is done before then works.

Thanks again and greetings!!

EDIT:

A few months later I've continued the project and I've found another way to make the background transparent: Remove the transparency converting it to solid white:

```
def remove_transparency(im, bg_colour=(255, 255, 255)):
    # Only process if image has transparency (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
    if im.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA') or (im.mode == 'P' and 'transparency' in im.info):
            # Need to convert to RGBA if LA format due to a bug in PIL (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1963146)
            alpha = im.convert('RGBA').split()[-1]
            # Create a new background image of our matt color.
            # Must be RGBA because paste requires both images have the same format
            # (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8720632    and    http://stackoverflow.com/a/9459208)
            bg = Image.new("RGBA", im.size, bg_colour + (255,))
            bg.paste(im, mask=alpha)
            return bg

    else:
            return im

# Open the image
sbuf = BytesIO(campo[4])
im = Image.open(sbuf)

# Remove transparency (white background will be transparent on ImageList)
im2 = remove_transparency(im).convert("RGB")
im.close()

# Create an wx.Image from image
width, height = im2.size
image = wx.Image(width, height, im2.tobytes())
image = image.Size(wx.Size(48,48), wx.Point(2,2), 255, 255, 255)

# Convert it to Bitmap and add it to ImageList
image = image.ConvertToBitmap()
icon_image = self.il.Add(image)
sbuf.close()
```

I've changed slightly the way I store the images, and now they comes from a PNG stored on an SQLite DB BLOB (campo[4]).

Greetings!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you run that code but try as I might, I have been unable to do so and thus cannot be sure of the answer below.
A `wx.Image` has a range of "image handlers", of which, only the BMPHandler is loaded by default. I suspect that you need to load the PNGHandler before attempting `SetAlpha` and you should probably check the image with `HasAlpha` beforehand.
See: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Image.html

> Alpha channel support
>   Starting from wxWidgets 2.5.0 wx.Image supports alpha channel data, that is in addition to a byte for the red, green and blue colour components for each pixel it also stores a byte representing the pixel opacity. An alpha value of 0 corresponds to a transparent pixel (null opacity) while a value of 255 means that the pixel is 100% opaque. The constants IMAGE_ALPHA_TRANSPARENT and IMAGE_ALPHA_OPAQUE can be used to indicate those values in a more readable form. While all images have RGB data, not all images have an alpha channel. Before using wx.Image.GetAlpha you should check if this image contains an alpha channel with wx.Image.HasAlpha . Currently the BMP, PNG, TGA, and TIFF format handlers have full alpha channel support for loading so if you want to use alpha you have to use one of these formats. If you initialize the image alpha channel yourself using wx.Image.SetAlpha , you should save it in either PNG, TGA, or TIFF format to avoid losing it as these are the only handlers that currently support saving with alpha.
>
> Available image handlers     The following image handlers are
>   available. BMPHandler is always installed by default. To use other
>   image formats, install the appropriate handler with
>   wx.Image.AddHandler or call wx.InitAllImageHandlers .
>
> BMPHandler: For loading (including alpha support) and saving, always
>   installed.
>   wx.PNGHandler: For loading and saving. Includes alpha
>   support.
>   wx.JPEGHandler: For loading and saving.
>   wx.GIFHandler: For loading and saving (see below).
>   wx.PCXHandler: For loading and saving (see below).
>   wx.PNMHandler: For loading and saving (see below).
>   wx.TIFFHandler: For loading and saving. Includes alpha support.
>   wx.TGAHandler: For loading and saving. Includes alpha support.
>   wx.IFFHandler: For loading only. wx.XPMHandler: For loading and saving.
>   ICOHandler: For loading and saving. CURHandler: For loading and saving.
>   ANIHandler: For loading only.
>   When saving in PCX format, wx.PCXHandler will count the number of different colours in the image; if there are 256 or less colours, it will save as 8 bit, else it will> save as 24 bit. Loading PNMs only works for ASCII or raw RGB images.
>   When saving in PNM format, wx.PNMHandler will always save as raw RGB.
>   Saving GIFs requires images of maximum 8 bpp (see Quantize ), and the
>   alpha channel converted to a mask (see wx.Image.ConvertAlphaToMask ).
>   Saving an animated GIF requires images of the same size (see
>   wx.GIFHandler.SaveAnimation )
>
> See also wx.Bitmap, wx.InitAllImageHandlers , PixelData

Comment: I've tested the handler but same behaviour . I've already tried a lot of things like test if there is alpha channel (true), getting alpha data of some pixels with diferent values on gradient zone (from 0 to 255), removing the alpha channel (then the whole box becomes red), and converting the alpha into mask with the built-in function... That's why I ask, I've searched about two days and tested a lot of things and I don't know what else to try. I'll give a try with mask again.